Purpose of worshipping a ugra Devi and devtas?
There are many ugra devtas in Hindu pantheon like Narasimha , Shamshad Kali, ugra Tara ,Chinnamasta , Chandi , Chamunda ,matangi ,dhumavati , bhairava etc,. Worshipping especially Kali and maa Tara is very dangerous according to tantriks, then why are such deities worshipped as they can harm an individual? What’s the point of worshipping Chinnamasta Isfahan one’s lineage is going to be destroyed and if the sadhana commits mistake then he/she dies . Also hat are the benefits obtained by the sadhana by worshipping these ugra devatas ? Thank you.
